# 65K LIMIT using play-services-ads and play-services-analytics

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services, dex

I can't use this two libraries in my app without reaching the 65K methods limit. Ads has ~24.000 methods and Analtycs has ~18.000.

I checked their depency list and both of them are using `support-v4:23.0.0` (~8.500 methods). I'm already using `support-v4:24.2.0` on my project, so how can I exclude `support-v4:23.0.0` of those libraries and force them to use support-v4:24.2.0?

I'm using this version by the way:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.4.0'
```

Comment: have you tried Proguard ? https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets

Comment: Also consider multidex, too.  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Comment: @Emme Multidex is off the table for the moment, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @PopTudor not really, if no one suggests another solution, I'll give it a try, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm already using `support-v4:24.2.0` on my project, so how can I exclude `support-v4:23.0.0` of those libraries and force them to use `support-v4:24.2.0`?

Gradle won't package two versions of `support-v4` into your app.
Run the gradle task `:dependencies` on your project to see which version is used.

---

If your projects exceeds the 65k methods limit you only have these options:

- Try to use fewer or other dependencies
- Use multidex
- Use proguard to strip unused code